# Are mediaqueries event listeners

Tags: css, media-queries

Are css mediaqueries some sort of event listeners (listening for a window resize) or does the browser check for them occasionally? If the letter, when or how often?

Comment: Pretty sure they work like event listeners, but the spec doesn't say anything about implementation. http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries

Comment: Window resize fires an event.

Answer (score 0):

For instance, WebKit sets up internal listeners that re-evaluate queries whenever "important" properties (window size, orientation, etc.) change, but this is not exposed through any APIs.

Comment: Then mediaqueries behave like the APIs for those listeners, right?

Comment: Since we may get confused in the term usage (media query, media list, media query list listener, etc.), I'd suggest that you have a look at the WebKit implementation at http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebCore/css/ (the files you are looking for contain "MediaQuery" in their names.)